# How to slice a ul so that every 6th items are wrapped in a ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list element where the number of li can be as many as can be imagined.

I want to slice it such that I wrap the first 6th elements with a ul, then the next 6th with another ul, then then next 6th with another ul, until all elements are wrapped.

Here is my html

```
<div id="flexslider" class="flexslider" data-item="4">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

And my jQuery to do the wrapping

```
for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i += dataItem) {
  item.slice(i, i + dataItem).wrapAll('<ul class="items"></ul>');
}
```

I expected the above jQuery to give me the following output

```
  item.slice(0, 6).wrapAll('<ul class="items"></ul>');
  item.slice(6, 12).wrapAll('<ul class="items"></ul>');
  item.slice(12, 18 + dataItem).wrapAll('<ul class="items"></ul>');
```

However, it did not create the three uls. It created two.

What am I doing wrong? How can I create the three ul?

Comment: What is `item` and `dataItem`?

Comment: Can't just wrap them ...`<ul>` can't be a direct child of `<ul>`. What are your expected results?

Comment: Take a step back, here's a small fiddle that shows how to split an array of items into groups. See if you can adapt this to your needs: https://jsfiddle.net/2e28L0hd/1/ Note the `Math.ceil` if I have 13 items, and I divide by 6 I get a little more than 2. If I use that in a for loop, it will only run twice. `Math.ceil` "adds" 1 in that case

Comment: Thanks all. I was able to solve it  as https://codepen.io/hellouniverse/full/LLJzgM